# T-SQL or PowerShell to move bak files older than 2 days to another location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, disk-space, powershell

I'm using SQL Server 2005. One of my backup drives is filling up, so I want to move backups older than 2 days.

I was thinking of creating a job to run everyday, but got stuck on the scripts moving the `.bak` files.

Do you know a script to move files from drive A and move it to a shared location? My `.bak` files doesn't have a timestamp.

Comment: This will help : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/78702/8783

Comment: you can check backupset table for information on your backup and then move files with xp_cmdshell

Comment: Just note that it may make sense to build in logic such that you're not just moving files that are two days old, but you are keeping log files that belong to the oldest full backup from two days ago, that sort of thing. If you have to restore and your full backup and the first chunk of log files have been moved to some other location and you still have a bunch of newer log files locally, that's going to be a pain.

Comment: Of course, if you're in simple recovery and only taking full backups, your problem here is much simpler (but your overall problem is a little harder, e.g. if you have to restore, you can't restore to a point in time).

Comment: @ Aaron. thanks.. Those are only full backups. You are right, if it had log files. I had a situation long time ago, and have to match a numerous number of LSNs to load logs. was not fun at all (:

Answer (score 5):

This Powershell example will find all .bak files older than two days in the c:\backup folder and move them to \shared\archive shared drive.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\backup\*.bak |where {$_.LastWritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-2)} |move-item -Destination \\shared\archive
```

Note you cannot run PowerShell commands directly in SSMS. Try it in a SQL Server Agent job step, or just in a PowerShell command window. Should work fine in either.